# ionic 2 using nav push to send data between pages

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Hi I'm new to ionic and I'm trying to use nav push to send my username to the next page.

Here are my codes on my first .js page, note that Index is the name of my 2nd page which has been imported.

```
this.nav.push(Index, { paramUser: 'asd' });
```

now on my second page.

```
 import {Component} from "@angular/core";
 import {NavController, NavParams} from "ionic-angular";

 @Component({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/index/index.html'
})
export class Index {


static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
}

constructor(nav, navParams) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.navParams = navParams;
    this.navParams.get('paramUser');
}


}
```

however i kept am receiving 'undefined' when I moved on to my second page, may I know what's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother you may missing  second  element  in array which  returns from  static get parameters function see below how it is.

```
static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController], [NavParams]];
  }
```

Other than this everything looks ok in your code sample.

Please let me know if solve otherwise will research more.

## webonerd

Comment: hi hi! i did tried to add that in but it seems to have the same issue, nevertheless i'll try it again and update you.

Comment: OHHH, I REALIZE i mis-typed something, that's why it doesn't work just now, THANKS!!! @webonerds

Comment: Great @Yubin Qiu ,  Have fun with Ionic 2